# Local vs Absolute Coordinates in Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/mfcqx7vw/

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var block = s.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 20, 20);
block.attr({
    fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",
    stroke: "#1f2c39",
    strokeWidth: 3
});

block.animate({ transform: "T0,0" }, 200);
```

I'm trying to translate this box to 0,0 - which would be the upper left side of the screen. But it doesn't move. So it's treating my capital T as lowercase t and using local coordinates. How do I get it to use absolute?

Comment: I think there is slight confusion here. The transform is already at 0,0. You are transforming absolutely it to 0,0, but its not moving as it's already there (it's just your x,y isn't..these are different things). So if you want to actually move the whole shape to 0,0 you have to either change x,y to 0,0 or transform T-100,-100. Think about a square at 100,100 on graph paper. You can either redraw the square at 0,0 (change x,y) or move the whole graph paper to the left by -100,-100. https://jsfiddle.net/mfcqx7vw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snap is transforming absolutely already. It's just that the current SVG hasn't been moved by a transform, it's been set with x,y.

So you have 2 choices, animate the x,y or animate the transform and leave x,y alone.

Behind the scenes in the DOM, a transform does NOT change the x,y. It has a separate transform attribute. The two are not linked in any way.

```
block.animate({ transform: "t-100,-100", 200 );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfcqx7vw/1/)

or

```
block.animate({ x: 0, y: 0 }, 200 );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfcqx7vw/2/)

It depends really what you are trying to achive, there's no right or wrong way, but if you wanted a solution that will work for circles and groups for example (as a circle doesn't have an x,y it has cx, cy) then a transform may be the way to go.

Think about the svg elements as being on graph paper. You can either reposition the element on the graph paper, or move the whole graph paper.

Now, if you really wanted to do a relative transform, you would have to have a transform on it in the first place for it to be relative to (otherwise its relative to default of 0,0 top left).

So if we start off by creating a rect without using x,y and using a transform of t100,100 to move it into the same place

```
var block = s.rect(0, 0, 100, 100, 20, 20).transform('t100,100');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfcqx7vw/4/)

You could then move it relative to that initial transform positioning, by including the existing transform first. So it would look like...

```
block.animate({ transform: block.transform() + "t-100,-100" }, 200);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfcqx7vw/5/)

This will relatively will move it -100,-100 more to the left, and up.

If you wanted absolute, it would be..

```
block.animate({ transform: "t0,0", 200 );
```